# why do i get redirected to a blank page after running javascript alert in php?

Tags: php

Register form, when the username is left empty this is the code that will run in script.php

```
if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
    echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'> alert('You must enter a username')</script>";
    exit();
```

The alert pops up on the browser but then tries to load script.php after the code has run causing a blank page to pop up shortly after. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Don't redirect to another page in the first place if that's not what you want. Learn about AJAX.

Comment: Not really enough of your code shown to be sure, but if that code is all that is in the script, you get a page with nothing in it as you have placed nothing in it

Comment: "then tries to load script.php" — It looks like that the code you've provided **is** `script.php`, so it tries to load that and **then** it shows the alert (because that is what the page says it should do).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol – A test like that doesn't need Ajax. `if (myInput.value === "") { ... }`

Comment: @Quentin True. In fact it doesn't even need JavaScript. `<input type="..." required />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors with your code example.

First, the obvious:

```
exit();
```

will cause the PHP script to stop immediately. Thus, any code/output afterwards won't be executed/rendered. Second, if you want to use javascript to check the form input, do it **before** the form is submitted. That is, intercept the click action of the submit button, run your validations and only if there is no issue actually send the form information to the server.